# create vm using pyvbox module

Tags: python-2.7, virtualbox

I'm using the pyvbox, the complete implementation of the virtualBox main API. In my use case i just want to write a python code in order to start and stop VMs. When i use python GUI every things works fine.But when i try to run the python code from the CMD i got this error:

```
echec de l'ouverture de session pour la machine 'test'

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!
Program: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxSVC.exe

R6025
-pure virtual function call
```

PS:

1. python version 2.7.11
2. pyvbox 1.0.0
3. OS windows 8

startvm.py:

```
import virtualbox
vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
session = virtualbox.Session()
vm = vbox.find_machine('test_vm')
progress = vm.launch_vm_process(session, 'gui', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you don't need any help on this anymore :D, but I write it here anyway, maybe it can be helpful to someone.

Starting and stopping a VM with the python pyvbox library is very simple:

```
import virtualbox

from vboxapi import VirtualBoxManager

vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
session = virtualbox.Session()

# This part starts the machine:
# machine_name is a simple string containing the name of your VM. For example "ubuntu"
machine = vbox.find_machine(machine_name)  
proc = machine.launch_vm_process(session, "headless")
proc.wait_for_completion(timeout=-1)

# This part stops it:
process, unused_variable = session.machine.take_snapshot("snapshot_name", "snapshot_description", False)  
# False means "do not pause the machine while snapshotting"
process.wait_for_completion(timeout=-1)
session.unlock_machine()
```

I created a simple script to automatically snapshot my virtual machines.

GitHub:
https://github.com/Meru3m/virtualbox-snapshotter

Comment: [tag:python3] 
[tag:virtualbox]
[tag:pyvbox]  
[tag:snapshot]